# Lazy loading not working for many-to-one relationship when mapping to a non-key field using property-ref

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading, icriteria

I have a legacy database that I am mapping using NHibernate. The objects of concern are an Account and a list of Notification objects. The objects look like:

```
public class Notification
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime BatchDate { get; set; }
    /* other properties */

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}

public class Account 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    /* other properties */ 
}
```

The mapping files look like:

```
<class name="Account" table="Account" dynamic-update="true">
<id name="Id" column="AccountID">
    <generator class="native" />
</id>
<property name="AccountNumber" length="15" not-null="true" />
    <!-- other properties -->
</class>

<class name="Notification" table="Notification">
    <id name="Id" column="Id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <!-- other properties -->
    <many-to-one name="Account" class="Account" property-ref="AccountNumber" lazy="proxy">
        <column name="AcctNum" />
    </many-to-one>
```

However, when I create a criteria such as

```
return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Notification)).List<Notification>();
```

I am getting a Select N+1 case where each account is loaded even though the Account is never referenced. Why are all of the accounts getting loaded when the many-to-one is mapped as a lazy proxy?

Comment: I get the same issue, I do remember seeing a post somehwere saying many-to-one property ref's can't be lazy loaded, I just cant find the source.  This was with NH 1.2

Answer (score 15):

The issue is caused by the `property-ref` attribute.  Lazy loading only works when the `many-to-one` reference is using the other object's primary key since NHibernate assumes there's a foreign key constraint enforcing the validity of such a value.  With a non-primary key (indicated by the property-ref), NHibernate does not make this assumption and thus does not assume the related object must exist.  Since it does not want to create a proxy for an object that does not exist (i.e. should be null instead of a proxy), it eagerly fetches the remote object.  This same issue exists when `not-found="ignore"` is specified since this indicates that the foreign key relationship is not enforced and may result in a null reference.

See also:

- [NHibernate creates proxy via session.Load(), but not via Linq or Criteria API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643905/nhibernate-creates-proxy-via-session-load-but-not-via-linq-or-criteria-api/1649547#1649547)
- http://frankmao.com/2007/12/05/lazy-load-conflicts-with-property-ref-in-many-to-one-mapping/

Comment: Issue in NH seems to be in TwoPhaseLoad.cs - it inspects LoadedState and calls IType.ResolveIdentifier to translate KEYs into Entities or Proxies. The IType involved here is ManyToOne(PK=false,Uniq=true,eager=false). It ends up calling ResolveIdentifier(value,session,owner) from base EntityType.cs, and that one checks IsReferenceToPrimaryKey(=false) and calls LoadByUniqueKey(). This one in turn has interesting comment "TODO: implement caching? proxies??" (YAY). Then, combo of session.PersistenceContext.GetEntity(new EntityUniqueKey(..key)) + persister.LoadByUniqueKey(..key) fetch the entity.