# NHibernate creates proxy via session.Load(), but not via Linq or Criteria API

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading, criteria

I have an odd problem in my current project. Lazy loading for queries does not work. When I query a list, nhibernate fetches all associations separately.

I extracted small parts of it and put it into a separate solution. Basically what I've got now, is a Account-Table and a AccountSync-Table. Both have an ID and a URL, while the ID is just a db-guid.

My classes are:

```
public class HippoAccount
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Url { get; set; }
    public virtual HippoAccountSync Sync { get; set; }
}

public class HippoAccountSync
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Url { get; set; }
    public virtual HippoAccount Account { get; set; }
}
```

When I now load a object via it's guid:

```
var account = session.Load<HippoAccount>(accountId);
Console.WriteLine(NHibernateUtil.IsPropertyInitialized(account, "Sync"))
```

... it returns `false` and account itself is a proxy.

But when loading a list via the criteria API:

```
var account = (HippoAccount)session
    .CreateCriteria(typeof (HippoAccount))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", accountId))
    .List()[0];
```

... the property `Sync` gets initialized (firing a second select query), and the returned object is not a proxy.

Is that default behaviour? What am I getting wrong?

The mapping is:

```
<class name="HippoAccount" table="AllAccounts">
  <id name="Id" type="guid">
    <generator class="guid"/>
  </id>
  <property name="Url" />

  <many-to-one 
           class="HippoAccountSync"
           name="Sync"
           not-found="ignore"
           property-ref="Url">
    <column name="url" />
  </many-to-one>
</class>

<class name="HippoAccountSync"
       mutable="false"
       table="Accounts">

  <id name="Id" type="guid">
    <generator class="guid"/>
  </id>

  <property name="Url">
    <column name="serviceUri" />
  </property>

  <many-to-one class="HippoAccount"
               name="Account"
               property-ref="Url"
               not-found="ignore">

    <column name="serviceUri" />
  </many-to-one>

</class>
```

Comment: not sure if it's entirely related, but there are issues with not-found="ignore": http://nhjira.koah.net/browse/NH-1001 http://guildsocial.web703.discountasp.net/dasblogce/CommentView,guid,ba00b19d-bd60-442b-b2e7-935277a9f1eb.aspx

Comment: You're right. Another issue is the property-ref - it also disables lazy loading.
http://maonet.wordpress.com/2007/12/05/lazy-load-conflicts-with-property-ref-in-many-to-one-mapping/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After quite some more research, I found the answers. Answers, because there are many things that can prevent lazy loading in NHibernate.

1. **Query vs. session.Load:** When fetching an item via `session.Load()` you get a proxy. But as soon as you access **any** property, lets say the `Url`, the object is fetched including all it's associations that doesn't support lazy loading.
2. **property-ref:** Lazy loading only works over a objects id. When an property-association is resolved via a different column in the target entity, NH fetches it eagerly. *Not that this wouldn't be possible, it's just not implemented: [Bug](http://nhjira.koah.net/browse/NH-1001)*
3. **not-found="ignore"** allows **invalid** foreign keys, that is, if the referenced entity isn't found NH will init the property with null. NH doesn't intercept the property-access for lazy loading, but instead assignes a object proxy. With `not-found="ignore"` it can't decide if the property should be set to null or a proxy for the given, possibly invalid, foreign key. *This could possibly be solved by intercepting the property access.*
4. When disabling `not-found="ignore"` and `property-ref` the schema export would generate constraints that enforce a circular reference. Not good! The correct mapping would then be a constrained one-to-one relationship, where the key for `HippoAccountSync` must have a generator `foreign`.

**Resources**

- [Select statement issued for each not-found=ignore](http://nhjira.koah.net/browse/NH-1001)
- [Lazy-load conflicts with Property-ref in Many-to-One Mapping](http://maonet.wordpress.com/2007/12/05/lazy-load-conflicts-with-property-ref-in-many-to-one-mapping/)
- [Google groups discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/323142508570fb94)

Comment: With session.Load(), you can, of course, safely access the Id property of the proxy without hitting the database, since you gave the proxy the Id to begin with.

Comment: link to property-ref bug no longer exists, 404 error.  Any idea on this progress?