# Fluent-Nhibernate References and PropertyRef Doing a Select With Lazy Load

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am using `PropertyRef` for one of my `References` properties. With `LazyLoad()` it still does a Select and loads the `User` entity, even though I never "hit" the SalesPerson property.

**Order Mapping**

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
References(x => x.SalesPerson)
                        .LazyLoad()
                        .PropertyRef(x => x.Username)
                        .Column("rsm");
Map(x => x.Title);
```

**Order Class**

```
public class Order : BaseEntity
{
    ...
    public virtual User SalesPerson { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**User Mapping**

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
Map(x => x.Username).Column("login");
```

**User Class**

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
     public virtual string Username { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

**Generated Order Mapping**

```
<many-to-one class="Project.User" lazy="proxy" name="SalesPerson" property-ref="Username">
      <column name="rsm" />
</many-to-one>
```

**Executing Code**

```
var order = session.Get<Order>(1);
Console.WriteLine(order.Title);
```

Is there anyway to prevent the Select to load the User entity when I'm not using the `User` entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has to do with property-ref see
[NHibernate creates proxy via session.Load(), but not via Linq or Criteria API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643905/nhibernate-creates-proxy-via-session-load-but-not-via-linq-or-criteria-api)

And not that you asked, but also consider that many-to-one with proxy does not allow you to do type-checking if you subclass User, see
http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/28/nhibernate-new-feature-no-proxy-associations.aspx

Comment: Think I'm going to change my schema to use actual Ids, this whole thing is not worth the hassle and is bad practice. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a bug in NHibernate. It depends on your mapping.

First, remember that the reference map will join the key (primary key and foreign key) between 2 mapping tables. To prevent SELECT + 1, just ignore the key joint.

```
References(x => x.SalesPerson)
                    .LazyLoad()
                    .PropertyRef(x => x.Username)
                    WithForeignKeyName("none") //disable key join.
```