# Fluent nHibernate PropertyRef is eagerly fetching referenced records. Can I disable it?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

If I specify PropertyRef on References (Many to One) - it eagerly fetches all related records:

```
References(x => x.Panel).PropertyRef(x => x.Code).Not.Insert().Not.Update();
```

Can I disable that N + 1 select problem?

Here I can see that this problem is known, but is there any workaround?
[Lazy loading not working for many-to-one relationship when mapping to a non-key field using property-ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604373/lazy-loading-not-working-for-many-to-one-relationship-when-mapping-to-a-non-key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a workaround. But only becuase your many-to-one is readonly *(and we do not have to care about insert/udpate issues later)*. How? By introducing a virtual entity e.g. `PanelView`

```
// Readonly mapping, virtual class
// which ID role is playing column panel_CODE
public PanelViewMapping()
{
    Table("panel-table");
    Id(x => x.Code)
      .Column("panel_CODE")
      .GeneratedBy.Assigned();
    ...
```

Now, we have to adjust the POCO entity:

```
// instead of this
// public virtual Panel Panel { get; set; }
// we will have this
public virtual PanelView Panel { get; set; }
```

And then we can use it as a primary key mapping:

```
References(x => x.Panel)
  //.PropertyRef(x => x.Code)
 .Not.Insert()
 .Not.Update();
```

And all the features *(lazy loading)* will work properly.

Comment: Wow, this looks correct and promising. I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah, for legacy DB it is the way... wish it would help you. Of course, there are some issues if the relation should be editable. But for readonly... it will work. I tested ;) Good luck with NHibernate sir ;)